# Irregular forms of 'wear' for different verb meanings

Tags: irregular-forms

Does 'wear' have the same irregular forms for meaning: "to cause to deteriorate by use" as for: "to use habitually for clothing, adornment, or assistance".
I mean: do we use 'wear - wore - worn' in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all meanings of "wear" share the same irregular forms. There is no meaning of "wear" that has the form **weared*, for instance.

If there is a difference, any good dictionary will point this out.

Take the Merriam-Webster entry for "[hang](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hang)" as an example. For most meanings, the past tense is the irregular "hung", but for the meaning of dying or killing someone, it specifies the past form:

> **hang**
> *transitive verb*
> *1 b* : to suspend by the neck until dead **—often hanged in the past—** often used as a mild oath
> *// I'll be hanged*